# Generate unique ID in inputText on page load

Tags: jsf-2

I want to genrate a unique number in `<p:inputText>` on page load.

I can generate an unique value using `java.util.UUID`, but how can I set it on the value of the `<p:inputText>` on page load?

```
<p:inputText id="ptId" label="PatientId" value="#{addBB.pt.patientId}" />
```

Comment: You can invoke a method which will add `userId` to your `addBB.pt.patientId` automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the value during bean's (post)construction.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddBB {

    private Patient pt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        pt = new Patient();
        pt.setPatientId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this just by making `userId`, the default value for inputText like this -

```
value="#{beanName.userId}"
```

so that first use it like u want to use and then u can set the value of `userId` at any point of time as the unique id, just remember to `reRender` it.

Hope you got what u wanted....